# Stop all search threads when one find what I'm looking for? (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

Each of of these threads is searching through a different list of data objects for a serial number. If it finds it, it puts the object in the queue. Serial numbers are unique.

```
q = Queue.Queue(10)
thread_list = []
for i in range(0, 10):
   t = Thread(serial)
   thread_list.append(t)
   t.start()
```

Rather than waiting for all the threads to finish with:

```
for t in thread_list:
    t.join()
```

Is there any way to stop all the threads when one finds the serial number it's looking for?
And account for the possibility that it may not find the serial number and the queue will remain empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach is to use the queue...  In your thread runner class (which is what I assume serial is)

```
class FindSerial(Thread):
    def __init__(self, serial, queue):
         this.serial = serial
         this.queue  = queue
         super(FindSerial, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        .... 
        while LOOKING_FOR_SERIAL:
            if not self.queue.empty():
                  return
        ....

 ...
 for i in range(0, 10):
     t = FindSerial(serial, q)
 ...
```

Now by checking the queue on ever pass through the loop you can check to see if another thread has found the object you're looking for, if it's found then you just return from your run method which will allow the join() to reap the thread.

Note: I would probably only check empty ever N iterations through the loop to avoid lots of lock contention.